# Debug VSCode 1.38 doesn't work for python

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a python file, but when I try to debug this file, it doesn't work. First in VSCode, no problems have been detected. So when I start the debugging I have the following situation (see image)

[image]

But it begins to load (as seen in the following image), but then returns to the previous situation (image 1). And I can't do the debug, since the local variables are not loaded

[image]

I tried to change python debug settings in launch.json, but it didn't work either.

I used to have version 1.41 and change to version 1.38, but it doesn't work.

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: What does the terminal show as output? And why can't you use the latest release of VS Code? Are you at least using the latest version of the Python extension?

Comment: @BrettCannon I do not use the latest version of vscode, because it presents the same problem with debug, so I preferred to use an earlier version. And  I have the version 3.7.4 of python.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are running the latest version of VS Code and then try [opting into out debugger experiment for our new debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/2104). Basically you need to install our insiders build of the extension and add the settings:

```
"python.experiments.optInto": [
        "DebugAdapterFactory - experiment",
        "PtvsdWheels37 - experiment"
    ],
```